# Where is the Dakshina Kalika Stotram taken from?

Tags: scripture, tantra, translation-request, sanskrit, shaktism

The Dakshina Kalika Stotram in Sanskrit is a regularly recited hymn in many Bengali households, especially among Shaktites, that constitute the majority of Bengal. It is mentioned in almost all Bengali Kali Puja Paddhati texts, in their appendices. I would like to know the source of this Stotram. I am pretty sure it must have been taken from some Tantra.

Also I see certain spelling differences within the Stotram among books, so I'm going mention the one version of the Stotram which I think doesn't have any grammatical and *Chhandas* discrepancies. (Based on my limited Sanskrit grammar knowledge)

Since I couldn't find the source, I didn't find any translation of the Stotram either (the Puja Paddhati books only have the Sanskrit text) and I would like to know the meaning of the verses too. Also I think, `kulācāra` (কুলাচার/ कुलाचार) in this stotram refers to *'Kaula'* tantric practice or the order of Kali, that most Shaktas in East India adhere to (as opposed to *Srividya* among South Indian Shaktas), and not the traditions of one's family or *kula*. [It is usually called कालीकुल, कौल, कुलमार्ग (Devanagari)/ কালীকুল, কৌল, কুলমার্গ (Bengali) in Sanskrit or Bangla and കൗളം, കുളമാർഗ്ഗം (Malayalam)/ కౌళము, కుళమార్గము (Telugu)/ கௌளம், குளமார்க்கம் (Tamil)/ ಕೌಳ, ಕುಳಮಾರ್ಗ (Kannada) in South Indian languages.]

I am quoting the Stotram in Bengali script (which one would usually find), Devanagari and Latin.

Bangla:

```
শ্রীমদ্দক্ষিণকালিকাস্তোত্রম্—
ওঁ কৃশোদরি মহাচণ্ডি মুক্তকেশি বলিপ্রিয়ে।
কুলাচারপ্রসন্নাস্যে নমস্তে শঙ্করপ্রিয়ে॥
ঘোরদংষ্ট্রে কোটরাক্ষি কিটীশব্দপ্রসাধিনি।
ঘুরঘোররবাস্ফারে নমস্তে চিত্তবাসিনি॥
বন্ধুকপুষ্পসঙ্কাশে ত্রিপুরে ভয়নাশিনি।
ভাগ্যোদয়সমুৎপন্নে নমস্তে বরবন্দিনি॥
জয় দেবীজগদ্ধাত্রি ত্রিপুরাদ্যে ত্রিদেবতে।
ভক্তেভ্যঃ বরদে দেবি মহিষঘ্নি নমোঽস্তুতে॥
ঘোরবিঘ্নবিনাশায় কুলাচারসমৃদ্ধয়ে।
নমামি বরদে দেবি মুণ্ডমালাবিভূষণে॥
রক্তধারাসমাকীর্ণে করকাঞ্চীবিভূষিতে।
সর্ববিঘ্নহরে কালি নমস্তে ভৈরবপ্রিয়ে॥
নমস্তে দক্ষিণামূর্তে কালি ত্রিপুরভৈরবি।
ভিন্নাঞ্জনচয়প্রখ্যে প্রবীণশবসংস্থিতে॥
গলচ্ছোণিতধারাভিঃ স্মেরাননসরোরুহে।
পীনোন্নতকুচদ্বন্দ্বে নমস্তে ঘোরদক্ষিণে॥
আরক্তমুখশান্তাভির্নেত্রালিভির্বিরাজিতে।
শবদ্বয়কৃতোত্তংসে নমস্তে মদবিহ্বলে॥
পঞ্চাশন্মুণ্ডঘটিতমালালোহিতলোহিতে।
নানামণিবিশোভাঢ্যে নমস্তে ব্রহ্মসেবিতে॥
শবাস্থিকৃতকেয়ূরশঙ্খকঙ্কণমণ্ডিতে।
শববক্ষঃসমারূঢ়ে নমস্তে বিষ্ণুপূজিতে॥
শবমাংসকৃতগ্রাসে সাট্টহাসে মুহুর্মুহুঃ।
মুখশীঘ্রস্মিতামোদে নমস্তে শিববন্দিতে॥
খড়্গমুণ্ডধরে বামে সব্যেঽভয়বরপ্রদে।
দন্তুরে চ মহারৌদ্রে নমস্তে চণ্ডনায়িকে॥
ত্বং গতিঃ পরমা দেবী ত্বং মাতা পরমেশ্বরী।
ত্রাহি মাং করুণাসার্দ্রে নমস্তে চণ্ডনায়িকে॥
নমস্তে কালিকে দেবি নমস্তে ভক্তবৎসলে।
মূর্খতাং হর মে দেবি প্রতিভাজয়দায়িনি॥
গদ্যপদ্যময়ীং বাণীং তর্কব্যাকরণাদিকম্।
অনধীতগতাং বিদ্যাং দেহি দক্ষিণকালিকে॥
জয়ং দেহি সভামধ্যে ধনং দেহি ধনাগমে।
দেহি মে চিরজীবিত্বং কালিকে রক্ষ দক্ষিণে॥
রাজ্যং দেহি যশো দেহি পুত্রান্ দারান্ ধনং তথা।
দেহান্তে দেহি মে মুক্তিং জগন্মাতঃ প্রসীদ মে॥
ওঁ মঙ্গলা ভৈরবী দুর্গা কালিকা ত্রিদশেশ্বরী।
উমা হৈমবতীকন্যা কল্যাণী ভৈরবেশ্বরী॥
কালী ব্রাহ্মী চ মাহেশী কৌমারী বৈষ্ণবী তথা।
বারাহী বাসলী চণ্ডী ত্বাং জগুর্মুনয়ঃ সদা॥
উগ্রতারেতি তারেতি শিবেত্যেকজটেতি চ।
লোকোত্তরেতি কালীতি গীয়তে কৃতিভিঃ সদা॥
যথা কালী তথা তারা তথা ছিন্না চ কুল্লুকা।
একমূর্তিশ্চতুর্ভেদা দেবি ত্বং কালিকা পুরা॥
একদ্বিত্রিবিধা দেবী কোটিধানন্তরূপিণী।
অঙ্গাঙ্গিকৈর্নামভেদৈঃ কালিকেতি প্রগীয়তে॥
শম্ভুঃ পঞ্চমুখেনৈব গুণান্ বক্তুং ন তে ক্ষমঃ।
চাপল্যৈর্যৎ কৃতং স্তোত্রং ক্ষমস্ব বরদা ভব॥
প্রাণান্ রক্ষ যশো রক্ষ পুত্রান্ দারান্ ধনং তথা।
সর্বকালে সর্বদেশে পাহি মাং দক্ষিণকালিকে॥
যঃ সংপূজ্য পঠেৎ স্তোত্রং দিবা বা রাত্রিসন্ধ্যয়োঃ।
ধনং ধান্যং তথা পুত্রং লভতে নাত্র সংশয়ঃ॥
—ইতি মহাকালবিরচিতং শ্রীমদ্দক্ষিণকালিকাস্তোত্রং সমাপ্তম্॥
```

Devanagari:

```
श्रीमद्दक्षिणकालिकास्तोत्रम्—
ॐ कृशोदरि महाचण्डि मुक्तकेशि बलिप्रिये।
कुलाचारप्रसन्नास्ये नमस्ते शङ्करप्रिये॥
घोरदंष्ट्रे कोटराक्षि किटीशब्दप्रसाधिनि।
घुरघोररवास्फारे नमस्ते चित्तवासिनि॥
बन्धुकपुष्पसङ्काशे त्रिपुरे भयनाशिनि।
भाग्योदयसमुत्पन्ने नमस्ते वरवन्दिनि॥
जय देवीजगद्धात्रि त्रिपुराद्ये त्रिदेवते।
भक्तेभ्यः वरदे देवि महिषघ्नि नमोऽस्तुते॥
घोरविघ्नविनाशाय कुलाचारसमृद्धये।
नमामि वरदे देवि मुण्डमालाविभूषणे॥
रक्तधारासमाकीर्णे करकाञ्चीविभूषिते।
सर्वविघ्नहरे कालि नमस्ते भैरवप्रिये॥
नमस्ते दक्षिणामूर्ते कालि त्रिपुरभैरवि।
भिन्नाञ्जनचयप्रख्ये प्रवीणशवसंस्थिते॥
गलच्छोणितधाराभिः स्मेराननसरोरुहे।
पीनोन्नतकुचद्वन्द्वे नमस्ते घोरदक्षिणे॥
आरक्तमुखशान्ताभिर्नेत्रालिभिर्विराजिते।
शवद्वयकृतोत्तंसे नमस्ते मदविह्वले॥
पञ्चाशन्मुण्डघटितमालालोहितलोहिते।
नानामणिविशोभाढ्ये नमस्ते ब्रह्मसेविते॥
शवास्थिकृतकेयूरशङ्खकङ्कणमण्डिते।
शववक्षःसमारूढे नमस्ते विष्णुपूजिते॥
शवमांसकृतग्रासे साट्टहासे मुहुर्मुहुः।
मुखशीघ्रस्मितामोदे नमस्ते शिववन्दिते॥
खड्गमुण्डधरे वामे सव्येऽभयवरप्रदे।
दन्तुरे च महारौद्रे नमस्ते चण्डनायिके॥
त्वं गतिः परमा देवी त्वं माता परमेश्वरी।
त्राहि मां करुणासार्द्रे नमस्ते चण्डनायिके॥
नमस्ते कालिके देवि नमस्ते भक्तवत्सले।
मूर्खतां हर मे देवि प्रतिभाजयदायिनि॥
गद्यपद्यमयीं वाणीं तर्कव्याकरणादिकम्।
अनधीतगतां विद्यां देहि दक्षिणकालिके॥
जयं देहि सभामध्ये धनं देहि धनागमे।
देहि मे चिरजीवित्वं कालिके रक्ष दक्षिणे॥
राज्यं देहि यशो देहि पुत्रान् दारान् धनं तथा।
देहान्ते देहि मे मुक्तिं जगन्मातः प्रसीद मे॥
ॐ मङ्गला भैरवी दुर्गा कालिका त्रिदशेश्वरी।
उमा हैमवतीकन्या कल्याणी भैरवेश्वरी॥
काली ब्राह्मी च माहेशी कौमारी वैष्णवी तथा।
वाराही वासली चण्डी त्वां जगुर्मुनयः सदा॥
उग्रतारेति तारेति शिवेत्येकजटेति च।
लोकोत्तरेति कालीति गीयते कृतिभिः सदा॥
यथा काली तथा तारा तथा छिन्ना च कुल्लुका।
एकमूर्तिश्चतुर्भेदा देवि त्वं कालिका पुरा॥
एकद्वित्रिविधा देवी कोटिधानन्तरूपिणी।
अङ्गाङ्गिकैर्नामभेदैः कालिकेति प्रगीयते॥
शम्भुः पञ्चमुखेनैव गुणान् वक्तुं न ते क्षमः।
चापल्यैर्यत् कृतं स्तोत्रं क्षमस्व वरदा भव॥
प्राणान् रक्ष यशो रक्ष पुत्रान् दारान् धनं तथा।
सर्वकाले सर्वदेशे पाहि मां दक्षिणकालिके॥
यः संपूज्य पठेत् स्तोत्रं दिवा वा रात्रिसन्ध्ययोः।
धनं धान्यं तथा पुत्रं लभते नात्र संशयः॥
—इति महाकालविरचितं श्रीमद्दक्षिणकालिकास्तोत्रं समाप्तम्॥
```

Latin: (IAST phonetic standard)

```
śrīmaddakṣiṇakālikāstotram—
oṃ kṛśodari mahācaṇḍi muktakeśi balipriẏe.
kulācāraprasannāsye namaste śaṅkarapriẏe..
ghoradaṃṣṭre koṭarākṣi kiṭīśabdaprasādhini.
ghuraghoraravāsphāre namaste cittavāsini..
bandhukapuṣpasaṅkāśe tripure bhaẏanāśini.
bhāgyodaẏasamutpanne namaste varavandini..
jaẏa devījagaddhātri tripurādye tridevate.
bhaktebhyaḥ varade devi mahiṣaghni namo'stute..
ghoravighnavināśāẏa kulācārasamṛddhaẏe.
namāmi varade devi muṇḍamālāvibhūṣaṇe..
raktadhārāsamākīrṇe karakāñcīvibhūṣite.
sarvavighnahare kāli namaste bhairavapriẏe..
namaste dakṣiṇāmūrte kāli tripurabhairavi.
bhinnāñjanacaẏaprakhye pravīṇaśavasaṃsthite..
galacchoṇitadhārābhiḥ smerānanasaroruhe.
pīnonnatakucadvandve namaste ghoradakṣiṇe..
āraktamukhaśāntābhirnetrālibhirvirājite.
śavadvaẏakṛtottaṃse namaste madavihvale..
pañcāśanmuṇḍaghaṭitamālālohitalohite.
nānāmaṇiviśobhāḍhye namaste brahmasevite..
śavāsthikṛtakeẏūraśaṅkhakaṅkaṇamaṇḍite.
śavavakṣaḥsamārūr̤he namaste viṣṇupūjite..
śavamāṃsakṛtagrāse sāṭṭahāse muhurmuhuḥ.
mukhaśīghrasmitāmode namaste śivavandite..
khar̤gamuṇḍadhare vāme savye'bhaẏavaraprade.
danture ca mahāraudre namaste caṇḍanāẏike..
tvaṃ gatiḥ paramā devī tvaṃ mātā parameśvarī.
trāhi māṃ karuṇāsārdre namaste caṇḍanāẏike..
namaste kālike devi namaste bhaktavatsale.
mūrkhatāṃ hara me devi pratibhājaẏadāẏini..
gadyapadyamaẏīṃ vāṇīṃ tarkavyākaraṇādikam.
anadhītagatāṃ vidyāṃ dehi dakṣiṇakālike..
jaẏaṃ dehi sabhāmadhye dhanaṃ dehi dhanāgame.
dehi me cirajīvitvaṃ kālike rakṣa dakṣiṇe..
rājyaṃ dehi yaśo dehi putrān dārān dhanaṃ tathā.
dehānte dehi me muktiṃ jaganmātaḥ prasīda me..
oṃ maṅgalā bhairavī durgā kālikā tridaśeśvarī.
umā haimavatīkanyā kalyāṇī bhairaveśvarī..
kālī brāhmī ca māheśī kaumārī vaiṣṇavī tathā.
vārāhī vāsalī caṇḍī tvāṃ jagurmunaẏaḥ sadā..
ugratāreti tāreti śivetyekajaṭeti ca.
lokottareti kālīti gīẏate kṛtibhiḥ sadā..
yathā kālī tathā tārā tathā chinnā ca kullukā.
ekamūrtiścaturbhedā devi tvaṃ kālikā purā..
ekadvitrividhā devī koṭidhānantarūpiṇī.
aṅgāṅgikairnāmabhedaiḥ kāliketi pragīẏate..
śambhuḥ pañcamukhenaiva guṇān vaktuṃ na te kṣamaḥ.
cāpalyairyat kṛtaṃ stotraṃ kṣamasva varadā bhava..
prāṇān rakṣa yaśo rakṣa putrān dārān dhanaṃ tathā.
sarvakāle sarvadeśe pāhi māṃ dakṣiṇakālike..
yaḥ sampūjya paṭhet stotraṃ divā vā rātrisandhyaẏoḥ.
dhanaṃ dhānyaṃ tathā putraṃ labhate nātra saṃśaẏaḥ..
—iti mahākālaviracitaṃ śrīmaddakṣiṇakālikāstotraṃ samāptam..
```

Would be glad if someone could help out either with the source or the translation or both. If you find any verse in the Stotra which feels grammatically funny, please do mention.

Comment: Most probably from the Sri Kalika Purana.